# Displaying Certain Assigned Values from each line of a text document

Tags: java, arrays, string

So I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make my code such that a student name is displayed from a text file along with a corresponding student score and store them into specific variables.There are 3 lines of text so my program must have 3 different names and 3 different scores being output. My text file has basic student info like this:

```
name1    score1;
name2    score2;
name3    score3;




import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.lang.reflect.Array;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ReadData 
  {

   public static void readData() throws FileNotFoundException 
     {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
     String[] names = new String[50];    
     int[] scores = new int[100]; 
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
     int l = 0;
     int w = 0;
     int z =0;




     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
     String line = scanner.nextLine();
     String [] words = line.split("\t"); 
     names[l] = words[0]; 
     scores[l] = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
     //System.out.println(" name: " + names[l] + ", score: " + scores[l]);
     //l++; 
     String line1 = scanner.nextLine();
     String [] words1 = line1.split("\t"); 
     names[w] = words1[0]; 
     scores[w] = Integer.parseInt(words1[1]);
    // w++;
     String line2 = scanner.nextLine();
     String [] words2 = line2.split("\t"); 
     names[z] = words2[0]; 
     scores[z] = Integer.parseInt(words2[1]);
     //z++;
    System.out.println(" name: " + names[l] + ", score: " + scores[l]);
    System.out.println(" name: " + names[w] + ", score: " + scores[w]);
    System.out.println(" name: " + names[z] + ", score: " + scores[z]);





     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: are you still online ?

Comment: yes i am.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must do this , at each step you must read a line of the file , then use the `split` method to split them , then you must associate it to your arrays , you define a counter , let me name it `j`, `j` must be equal to **zero** at first , after writing a line into our array we increment the value of `j` so that we can write another value into the next place of the array

```
float sum = 0 ;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
     String line = scanner.nextLine();
     String [] words = line.split("\t"); 
     names[l] = words[0]; 
     scores[l] = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
     sum+=scores[l];
     System.out.println(" name: " + names[l] + ", score: " + scores[l]);
     l++; 
}
System.out.println(sum/l);
```

Comment: Also, size of array should be 3 instead of 50 an 100

Comment: I have done that but when suppose i want to find the mean of their scores, i would need to have their scores in such a way that v = score1 or something im not sure

Comment: so this is another question

Comment: @JustAJAVAGUY you wanna calculate the mean ?

Comment: i found it helpful

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi yeah thats what im trying to do pretty much and im making enumerated types such that an A grade is = mean <= score

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi so how would i find the mean by assigning variables and not directly plugging in numbers?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you , i'll not repeat it again

Comment: @JustAJAVAGUY check my answer again

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi the mean value is wrong for some reason, I had 25,65, and 89 as my values and it outputted 44.75. Also how do you assign 25,65,89 from the text file to a variable that in my code that I can use in multiple classes?

Comment: @JustAJAVAGUY check my answer again

Comment: @JustAJAVAGUY you are associating values from files to your arrays , you can use call these arrays in other classes by making it `static` , depends on your implementation

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi yes it works now thank you:) how do you find each of the scores individually in case I want to link a student score to their name by giving each score a variable?